# why local variable changed automatically

Tags: c++, if-statement, binary-search-tree

I write a function to delete a node in binary search tree. 
Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
struct BSTNode
{
    int data;
    BSTNode *left;
    BSTNode *right;
};

BSTNode * GetNode(int data);
BSTNode * FindMin(BSTNode *root);
BSTNode * Insert(BSTNode *root, int data);
void PreOrder(BSTNode *root);
BSTNode * DeleteNode(BSTNode *root,int data);

BSTNode * GetNode(int data)
{
    BSTNode *newNode = new BSTNode;
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    return newNode;
}

BSTNode * FindMin(BSTNode *root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return root;
    while(root->left != NULL)
        root = root->left;
    return root;

}

BSTNode * Insert(BSTNode *root, int data)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root = GetNode(data);
        return root;
    }
    else if (data <= root->data)
        root->left = Insert(root->left, data);
    else if (data > root->data)
        root->right = Insert(root->right, data);
    return root;
}

void PreOrder(BSTNode *root)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return;
    std::cout << root->data << std::endl;
    PreOrder(root->left);
    PreOrder(root->right);
}

BSTNode * DeleteNode(BSTNode *root,int data)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return root;
    else if(data < root->data)
        root->left = DeleteNode(root->left, data);
    else if(data > root->data)
        root->right = DeleteNode(root->right, data);
    else // Found the Node
    {
        // case 1: No child
        if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
        {
            delete root;
            root = NULL;
            return root;
        }
        // case 2: One child
        else if(root->left == NULL)
        {
            BSTNode * temp = root;
            root = root->right;
            delete temp;
            return root;
        }
        else if(root->right = NULL)
        {
            BSTNode * temp = root;
            root = root->left;
            delete temp;
            return root;
        }
        else // case 3: two child
        {
            BSTNode * temp = FindMin(root->right);
            root->data = temp->data;
            root->right = DeleteNode(root->right, temp->data);
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    BSTNode *root = NULL;
    root = Insert(root, 15);
    root = Insert(root, 10);
    root = Insert(root, 20);
    root = Insert(root, 25);
    root = Insert(root, 8);
    root = Insert(root, 12);
    root = DeleteNode(root, 15);
    PreOrder(root);

    return 0;
}
```

but i across a problem with

```
else // case 3: two child
        {
            BSTNode * temp = FindMin(root->right);
            root->data = temp->data;
            root->right = DeleteNode(root->right, temp->data);
        }
```

when program came to else statement, root->right become NULL automatically

why this happen ? how can i fix it ?

any ideas appreciated!

Comment: `else if(root->right = NULL)` oops. `DeleteNode` doesn't always return something either. Turn your compiler warnings on!

Comment: i'm so careless! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have done some typo mistake in checking the following code

```
else if(root->right = NULL)
{
    BSTNode * temp = root;
    root = root->left;
    delete temp;
    return root;
}
```

The above line `else if(root->right = NULL)` should be `root->right == NULL` but you wrote as `root->Right = NULL`.